# 3D Tikzpicture and reversing axes, incorrect draw order for graph contour

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am attempting to draw a 3D contour plot of a function using `pgfplots` and `tikz`.  However, I have to reverse the Y-axis to match the way I'm showing the coordinate axes in other illustrations.  The correct way that the contour plot should look is shown below, just imagine the Y-axis numbering being reversed.

[image: correct image]

My MWE for this plot is shown below, but it includes the `y dir=reverse` command in order to flip the Y-axis values.  However, when I do this, it appears that the draw order for the contour is incorrect, as you can see in the next image.  The bulge in the plot appears tucked behind, which is not as intended.

How would I fix this issue in my plot?  I'm going for a contour plot that appears like the first image, just with the Y-axis values flipped.

[image: incorrect image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={grays}{gray(0cm)=(0.5);gray(1cm)=(0)}}
\pgfplotsset{samples=31}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            view={60}{30},
            axis equal image,
            width=\linewidth,
            xlabel style={align=center, anchor=north, rotate=-46.1},
            xlabel={Lateral Stress \\ $q_x$ [kPa]},
            xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{4*\tick}$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$},
            ylabel={Lateral Distance $y$ [m]},
            ylabel style={rotate=16.1},
            zlabel={Depth $z$ [m]},
            y dir=reverse
            ]
            \addplot3[
            patch,
            fill=white,
            opacity=0.8,
            samples=31,
            domain=-1:10,
            y domain=0:-6,
            point meta=x
            ]
            ({(1/4)*2*-70/(3.1415*2)*(2^3*y/(2^2+y^2)^2)*(%
                %
                ((8-x)*(3*(2^2+y^2)+2*(8-x)^2)/(2^2+(8-x)^2+y^2)^1.5)-%
                %
                ((1-x)*(3*(2^2+y^2)+2*(1-x)^2)/(2^2+(1-x)^2+y^2)^1.5)%
                )}, x, y);
            \addlegendentry{$q_x$}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only added `z buffer=sort` (and used the newest compatibility mode, but this is not important for the solution) to get

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={grays}{gray(0cm)=(0.5);gray(1cm)=(0)}}
\pgfplotsset{samples=31}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            view={60}{30},
            axis equal image,
            width=\linewidth,
            xlabel style={align=center, anchor=north, rotate=-46.1},
            xlabel={Lateral Stress \\ $q_x$ [kPa]},
            xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{4*\tick}$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$},
            ylabel={Lateral Distance $y$ [m]},
            ylabel style={rotate=16.1},
            zlabel={Depth $z$ [m]},
            y dir=reverse
            ]
            \addplot3[z buffer=sort,
            patch,
            fill=white,
            opacity=0.8,
            samples=31,
            domain=-1:10,
            y domain=0:-6,
            point meta=x
            ]
            ({(1/4)*2*-70/(3.1415*2)*(2^3*y/(2^2+y^2)^2)*(%
                %
                ((8-x)*(3*(2^2+y^2)+2*(8-x)^2)/(2^2+(8-x)^2+y^2)^1.5)-%
                %
                ((1-x)*(3*(2^2+y^2)+2*(1-x)^2)/(2^2+(1-x)^2+y^2)^1.5)%
                )}, x, y);
            \addlegendentry{$q_x$}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  I guess that's an indicator of how long ago I started this paper that I'm still using v1.13 for `pgfplots`!